# Recaptcha is blocking valid form submissions since beginning feb 2024

Tags: recaptcha, elementor

I use Recaptcha V3 across all my WordPress websites, adding it into elementor pro forms and have had no issues at all until the last few days.
When someone goes to submit their form it just comes back with a message saying 'invalid form, recaptcha validation failed suspected as abusive usage. I have tried it myself too.
Please can someone help, I'm having to check all websites and remove the option on the form which is now allowi9ng spam to flood in!
Thanks in advance.

I have tried removing and re-adding the keys, removing and re-adding the section on the form